# How can I count frequency of two items using two columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large file (5GB), and I need to count the number of occurence using two columns

```
     a   b   c   d   e
0    2   3   1   5   4
1    2   3   2   5   4
2    1   3   2   5   4
3    2   4   1   5   3
4    2   4   1   5   3
```

so obviously I have to find

```
(2,3):2
(1,3):1
(2,4):2
```

How can I do that in a very fast way.

I used:

```
df.groupby(['a','b']).count().to_dict()
```

Let's say that the final result would be

```
a b freq
2 3 2
1 3 1
2 4 2
```

Comment: Do you need a dictionary at the end? That eats up extra memory. I think that writing `df.groupby(['a','b']).size()` would be about as efficient as you could hope for.

Comment: can I add a columns this way df['freq'] = df.groupby(['a','b']).size() and delete the duplicates ?

Comment: @user3378649, do you want the rest of the dataframe or are you creating one just to get the two columns?

Comment: the result should be something similar to last df

Comment: @user3378649, yes but are the other columns relevant?

Answer (score 2):

### Approach for the first version of the question - dictionary as result

If you have high frequencies, i.e. few combinations of `a` and `b`, the final dictionary will be small. If you have many of different combinations, you will need lots of RAM.

If you have **low frequencies** and enough RAM, looks like your approach is good.

Some timings for 5e6 rows and numbers from 0 to 19:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 19, size=(5000000, 5)), columns=list('abcde'))
>>> df.shape
(5000000, 5)

%timeit df.groupby(['a','b']).count().to_dict() 
1 loops, best of 3: 552 ms per loop

%timeit  df.groupby(['a','b']).size()
1 loops, best of 3: 619 ms per loop

%timeit  df.groupby(['a','b']).count()
1 loops, best of 3: 588 ms per loop
```

Using a different range of integers, here up to `sys.maxsize` (9223372036854775807), changes the timings considerably:

```
import sys
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, high=sys.maxsize, size=(5000000, 5)), 
                  columns=list('abcde'))


%timeit df.groupby(['a','b']).count().to_dict() 
1 loops, best of 3: 41.3 s per loop

%timeit  df.groupby(['a','b']).size()
1 loops, best of 3: 11.4 s per loop

%timeit  df.groupby(['a','b']).count()
1 loops, best of 3: 12.9 s per loop`
```

### Solution for the updated question

```
df2 = df.drop(list('cd'), axis=1)
df2.rename(columns={'e': 'feq'}, inplace=True)
g = df2.groupby(['a','b']).count()
g.reset_index(inplace=True) 
print(g)

   a  b  feq
0  1  3    1
1  2  3    2
2  2  4    2
```

It is not much faster though.

For range 0 to 19:

```
%%timeit
df2 = df.drop(list('cd'), axis=1)
df2.rename(columns={'e': 'feq'}, inplace=True)
g = df2.groupby(['a','b']).count()
g.reset_index(inplace=True) 

1 loops, best of 3: 564 ms per loop
```

For range 0 to `sys.maxsize`:

```
%%timeit
df2 = df.drop(list('cd'), axis=1)
df2.rename(columns={'e': 'feq'}, inplace=True)
g = df2.groupby(['a','b']).count()
g.reset_index(inplace=True) 
1 loops, best of 3: 10.2 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! Double check the update, please note that I am processing 5G File

Comment: I want to get the result in the update. Is it recommended to reconstruct the DF, or just add one column directly and filter the duplicates later on

Comment: Why is `df.groupby(['a','b']).count()` slower than `df.groupby(['a','b']).count().to_dict() `? When I run the test, converting to a dictionary slows things down by a factor of 4 or so. (Also, for me, `size()` is marginally faster than `count()`.)

Comment: @ajcr This might depend on your test data. In fact, I am surprised myself that the version converting to the dictionary comes out a bit faster than  the one without. But they are pretty close.

Comment: But I don't see how adding an extra method call, especially one that creates a potentially large dictionary of Python objects, could *ever* be faster :-) fwiw, I tested with `df = DataFrame(randint(0, x, size=(5000000, 5)), columns=list('abcde'))` where `x` varied between a large and small number (for greater/fewer unique pairs).

Comment: @ajcr Agree. Repeated my measurements with your test data. See my updated answer. Maybe it has something to do with memory management. I am on OS X 10.9.

Comment: For me count and size are orders of magnitude faster on all variations of data

Comment: @ajcr  Figured it out. It is all about the data. I had a rather small range of integers. Added more timings with a larger range.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I think `size` and `count` should always be close in terms of performance (`size` was [improved](https://github.com/behzadnouri/pandas/commit/9608c8717d19a969771ad361c5239109310be20f) relatively recently). Anyway, upvoted for the range of timings.